# Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration, Nginx appending :8001 to the URL when signin request goes to Facebook

Tags: django, facebook, nginx, gunicorn

I've added facebook login to my site. However, when I click the signin button, I get a red box that says:

'Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains.'

When I dig deep, I find that my Nginx server is sending a request to facebook from  http://mydomain.com:8001/usersignin, I believe facebook doesn't accept :8001 in the URL, How can I prevent :8001 appending to the URL ?

Answer (score 0):

See the [port_in_redirect](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#port_in_redirect) directive